# Remove duplicate words after stripping punctuation

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

Let's say I have a file with the following contents:

```
VSDmaMapInfo
VSDmaMapInfo::
VSDmaMapInfo;
VSPortErr
VSPortErr,
VSPortErr::
```

and after sorting I wanted the output to be

```
VSDmaMapInfo
VSPortErr
```

Is there any way to do it using either grep, awk, uniq,or any other tools etc

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Strip punctuation, then get the unique lines? Oh, and what is it with the inconsistent uppercasing of `Vs`? Is that relevant?

Comment: Yes. That would do. Yeah my typo. It is always VS..

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'[[:punct:]]' '{print $1}' file | sort -u
VSDmaMapInfo
VSPortErr
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for sorted content with GNU sed

```
sed -r '$!N;/(\w+)\W*\n\1\W*/!{s/(\w+).*/\1/;P};D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
$ tr -d "[[:punct:]]" < file | sort -u
VSDmaMapInfo
VSPortErr
```

#### Explanation

```
tr -d "[[:punct:]]"            < file         |    sort -u
   remove puntuation chars     read file          get unique
```

#### Update

From your comment:

> I just had an observation: If the input containts VSDmaMapInfo::callMe
>   it is removing the punctuation but joining the next word like
>   VSDmaMapInfocallMe. Is it possible that I have the output as
>   VSDmapMapInfo only without the next word getting appended.

We can do the following:

```
$ cat file
VSDmaMapInfo
VSDmaMapInfo::
VSDmaMapInfo;
VSDmaMapInfo;asdfs
VSPortErr
VSPortErr,
VSPortErr::

$ awk -F"[,:;]" '{print $1}' file | sort -u
VSDmaMapInfo
VSPortErr
```

That is, make `awk` print the first word before any `,`, `:` or `;`. Then, sort it with `-u` parameter to have unique data.

Comment: Updated my answer. It previously had different cases for each name, so I included a pipe to put everything in lower case.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works. I just had an observation: If the input containts VSDmaMapInfo::callMe it is removing the punctuation but joining the next word like VSDmaMapInfocallMe. Is it possible that I have the output as VSDmapMapInfo only without the next word getting appended.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the deduplication is to happen case-insensitive, the following Perl-oneliner emits the wanted output:

```
perl -ne's/[[:punct:]]+$//;$h{lc $_}++ or print'
```

Test:

```
$ perl -ne's/[[:punct:]]+$//;$h{lc $_}++ or print' <<'END'
VSDmaMapInfo
VSDmaMapInfo::
VsDmaMapInfo;
VSPortErr
VsPortErr,
VsPortErr::
END
```

Output:

```
VSDmaMapInfo
VSPortErr
```

#### Edit:

For case-sensitive matching change `$h{lc $_}++` to `$h{$_}++`.

#### Edit2:

To remove anything after the first punctuation character on the line, replace the substitution by `s/[[:punct:]].*//`.

To call the one-liner with a file, you can list the input file(s) as command line arguments:

```
$ perl -ne'...' the-file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It is really helpful. Let's say I have a big file as the input how do i pass it your script.

Comment: @MarcSpencer You can pass a file as first command line argument, instead of the `<<'END'` here-doc: `perl -ne'...' the-file.txt`. You can also pipe the contents into the script, like `perl -ne'...' < the-file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Skips duplicate lines,

```
perl -nE 's|\W||g; say unless $h{$_}++' file
```

Answer (score 1):

sed solution ( basically sed + sort)

```
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]//g' <file> |sort -u
```

another clumsy awk solution

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,""); a[$0]=1} END{for(var in a) print var}' <file>
```

another awesome pure bash solution (I love to play around with bash :))

```
l=""
while read r
do
r=${r//[^[:alpha:]]/}
 if ! [[ $l =~ $r ]]
 then
 echo $r
 l="$l $r"
 fi
done < <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use GNU `awk`, you can use multiple characters as record separator (`RS`), so you can do this:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' RS='[[:punct:]]*\n' test.txt
```

Explanation:

1. By setting the record separator (`RS`) to this regex, we get rid of the trailing punctuations, so the record i.e. `$0` is a word.
2. We keep count of the words in `a`.

   - If the word is not a duplicate, `a[$0]` is 0, and `!a[$0]` evaluates to true, so the word gets printed out. Otherwise, it doesn't get printed out.

Comment: You should mention that this is GNU awk only.

Comment: @EdMorton, which part of it? The `[[::punc::]]`?

Comment: Setting RS to multiple characters. In POSIX and most other non-GNU awks the RS can only be a single character and all additional characters get ignored so what you specified above would actually set RS to the single character `[`.